# How to get id of active camera with javascript?

Tags: webrtc

I have successfully used webrtc to bind a local camera to a html  element. 
I have more than one camera connected to my pc.

How can I use javascript to find out the DeviceID of the camera, that is now in use?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Get the tracks from the MediaStream you get from getUserMedia, look at the label property.
See  https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/master/src/content/getusermedia/gum/js/main.js#L23 for a sample.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps, I don't understand you correctly -  but I'm not searching for the label but for the ID-Number.

Comment: the label is the most accurate thing you can get (for privacy reasons). It will be something like Integrated_Webcam_HD or whatever the manufacturer choose to expose to the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

#### 2022 Answer

###### (Not sure if the previous answer was correct in its time, but here's what I did to solve the same question.)

I assume the HTML element you bound the camera to was a video element. Here's how I got the the DeviceID from it.

```
const video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
const stream = video?.srcObject;
const videoTrack = stream?.getTracks()?.find(track => track.kind === "video");
const videoID = videoTrack?.getSettings().deviceId;
```